# Pyspark compare two columns that are lists

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a dataframe as below. The two columns are lists.

```
df= sc.parallelize([
            {"subject_1":['A','B'],"subject_2":['A','B','C']  },            
            {"subject_1":['A','C'],"subject_2":['A','B','C']  },             
            {"subject_1":['A','B','D'],"subject_2":['A','B','E']  }  
 ]).toDF()
df.show()
```

[image]

I need to convert the dataframe as below.Adding three new columns that are derived from the first two columns. This requires comparing the items in the list of the two columns.

[image]

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

For **`Spark2.4+`**, use **`array_intersect`** and **`array_except`**:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.withColumn("both", F.array_intersect("subject_1","subject_2"))\
  .withColumn("only_1", F.array_except("subject_1","subject_2"))\
  .withColumn("only_2", F.array_except("subject_2","subject_1")).show()

#+---------+---------+------+------+------+
#|subject_1|subject_2|  both|only_1|only_2|
#+---------+---------+------+------+------+
#|   [A, B]|[A, B, C]|[A, B]|    []|   [C]|
#|   [A, C]|[A, B, C]|[A, C]|    []|   [B]|
#|[A, B, D]|[A, B, E]|[A, B]|   [D]|   [E]|
#+---------+---------+------+------+------+
```

Comment: I am still on 2.3.

Comment: You'd need to write a UDF for it. Similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48549123/362792) except your data comes from 2 columns instead of a column and a pre-determined list.

Comment: @KeerikkattuChellappan without 2.4, udf is the only way forward. would recommend to update to 2.4 for future use of array or other higher ordered data.